# Spherical harmonics - Computing the variance of Poisson noise integrated over $\ell$ on a defined quantity?

Tags: statistics, variance, poisson-distribution, spherical-harmonics, noise

It is an astrophysics context but actually, it is mostly a mathematics issue.

From spherical harmonics with Legendre deccomposition, I have the following definition of
the standard deviation of a $C_\ell$ noised with a Poisson Noise $N_p$ :

\begin{equation}
\sigma({C_\ell})(\ell)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{(2 \ell+1) f_{sky}}}\left[C_\ell(\ell)+\dfrac{1}{N_{p}}\right]\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now I consider the quantity : $$\sum_{\ell=1}^{N} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}$$

I want to estimate the variance expression of Poisson Noise of this qantity.

For that, I take the definition of $a_{lm}$ following a normal distribution with mean equal to zero and take also the definition of a $C_\ell=\langle a_{lm}^2 \rangle=\dfrac{1}{2\ell+1}\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}\,a_{\ell m}^2 = \text{Var}(a_{lm})$.

I use $\stackrel{d}{=}$ to denote equality in distribution :
$$
\begin{split}
Z & \equiv \sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell, m}^{2} \\
& =\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \cdot\left(\frac{a_{\ell, m}}{\sqrt{C_{\ell}}}\right)^{2} \\
& \sim \sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \cdot \mathrm{ChiSq}(1) \\
&=\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} C_{\ell} \cdot \mathrm{ChiSq}(2 \ell+1).
\end{split}
$$
So Finally we have :
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^{N} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}  \stackrel{d}{=} \sum_{\ell=1}^{N}\,C_\ell \chi^{2}(2\ell+1).
$$
To compute the Poisson Noise of each $a_{\ell m}^2$, a colleague suggests me that for getting an optimal variance expression, I must use the [Inverse-variance_weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting), to take only the quantity below:
$$
\dfrac{2}{f_{sky}\,N_p^2},\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
and to do the summation to get the variance of Poisson Noise (to make the link with formula \eqref{1} and be consistent with it) :
$$
\text{Var}(N_{p,int})=\sum_{\ell=1}^{N} \dfrac{2}{f_{sky}\,N_p^2}. \label{3}\tag{3}
$$
But I have difficulties to understand the Inverse-variance_weighting applied in my case : I don't understand where are implied the weights regarding the formula \eqref{3}.

I wrote above $\text{Var}(N_{p,int})$, make caution, this is just to express the "integrated Poisson variance" over $\ell$ in the quantity
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^{N} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}.
$$
Unfortunately, when I do numerical computation with this variance formula \eqref{3}, I don't get the same variance than with another valid method.

Correct results are got by introducing a factor $\sqrt{2\ell+1}$ into formula \eqref{3}. But I don't know how to justify it, it is just fine-tuned from my part for the moment and it is not rigorous I admit.

**QUESTION :**

1. Is formula \eqref{2} that expresses the variance of Shot Noise on the quantity $\sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell a_{\ell,m}^2$ correct ?

   If yes, how could integrate it correctly by summing it on multipole $\ell$ and to remain consistent with the standard deviation formula \eqref{1} ? (I talk about the pre-factor $\sqrt{\frac{2}{(2 \ell+1) f_{sky}}}$ that disturbs me in the expression of integrated Poisson Noise)
2. Finally, from all given informations above, how to correctly compute analytically the variance of

$$\sum_{\ell=1}^{N} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}\:?$$